# Replacing nulls in a column range

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook, fillna

So I am editing a dataframe for a project and I need to replace null values in 105 columns with 'No answer'
in order to do this I wrote the following code but it only created a view of the updated dataframe. when I look at the actual dataframe nothing has actually changed. I find this odd because im using `loc` method and `fillna('No answer',interface=True)`. I thought by making interface = True it meant the actual dataframe would be updated and the same for `loc` function.

Code I used:

```
candy.loc[:,'Q6 | 100 Grand Bar':'Q11: DAY'].fillna('NO_ANSWER', inplace=True)
candy.loc[:,'Q6 | 100 Grand Bar':'Q11: DAY']
```

Second code just prints out the original dataframe for the columns I wanted to edited
You can see in the image that the Nan values are still there after running first code

Can any one explain my error in logic and why its not working as intended
and possible solutions. Pic below is what Im getting
[image]

Comment: Could you please give some examples of your inputs and expected outputs? Also specify what you already tried.

Comment: I just added a photo, you can see Im still getting NaN values after funning the remove null fillna function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using `.loc`, you are generating a new object, which is a `slice` of the original dataframe. `inplace=True` is applied to this new object, **not** the original dataframe, **hence** you see no changes in the original dataframe. So what you want to do is the following:

```
candy.loc[:,'Q6 | 100 Grand Bar':'Q11: DAY'] = candy.loc[:,'Q6 | 100 Grand Bar':'Q11: DAY'].fillna('NO_ANSWER')
```